# Permission denied error while using gpt-3.5-turbo-instruct for OpenAI embeddings

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence, openaiembeddings

```
Error code: 403 - {'error': {'message': 'You are not allowed to generate embeddings from this model', 'type': 'invalid_request_error', 'param': None, 'code': None}}
```

```
embeddings = OpenAIEmbeddings(model="gpt-3.5-turbo")
document_search = Chroma.from_texts(texts, embeddings)
```

Earlier it was working fine with text-davinci-003 model before not it is deprecated.